can't build old version of gradle
my gradle version is 6.1.1 and android gradle plugin is 4.0.1. two years ago there wasn't any problem, but now i cant build this project. how to solve it?
build.gradle:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"

        // for formBuilder
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

build.gradle:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.electricalcalculator"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 18
        versionName "2.3.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
}
...

i sync project but get error:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'ElectricalCalculator'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.7.3/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.7.3.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.7.3/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.7.3.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target```


Could be you have to change jcenter to mavenCentral.

i change it but dont work.

Could you please post the whole error, or is that all that's relevant?

@ZsoltBoldizsar its all error

A lot of artifacts were only published in jcenter repo. As this repo is now gone you have to find other sources (or versions) of the missing library.

You might've bumped into this blog post from the Gradle team: https://blog.gradle.org/portal-jcenter-impact where they mention that Bintray Gradle plugin is also affected by JCenter finally shutting down. If you add either maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" } or gradlePluginPortal() to buildscript { repositories {  you'll find the exact missing dependency they included in the csv file attached in the blog post, namely: org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.2..

But I believe you won't publish any new artifacts to Bintray anyway, so I'd remove the Bintray Gradle plugin completely and migrate to Maven Publish Gradle plugin once you need to start publishing again: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html
